# Find distribution of random variable Z:

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Independent observations $\ x_{1} , . . . , x_{n} , y_{1} , . . . , y_{k}$ are from the $\ N(μ, σ^{2} )$ distribution. Find distribution of random variable Z:
$\
Z =  \frac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}}{\sigma \sqrt{ \frac{n+k}{nk} } }.
$

Comment: To start: do you know the distribution of the sample mean of IID normal RVs?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 no I do not know

Answer (score 1):

Let us recall the following facts:

1. The sample mean of $n$ IID $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ RVs is distributed like $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$. Thus
   $$\bar{X}_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$$
   and
   $$\bar{Y}_k \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2/k).$$
   This can be proven by checking the MGFs.
2. The difference of two independent normals is normal again, specifically here,
   $$\bar{X}_n-\bar{Y}_k \sim \mathcal{N} \left(0, \sigma^2\frac{(n+k)}{nk}\right),$$
   again by checking the MGF.

Can you fill in these details as exercises now and conclude what the distribution of $Z=\frac{\bar{X}_n-\bar{Y}_k}{\sigma \sqrt{\frac{n+k}{nk}}}$ is?

Comment: I still don't see how to solve this

Comment: @Kondzio123 Well, and why not? What is confusing to you? Let me ask you this. Can you tell me, if $W \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, do you know what the distribution of $W/\sigma$ is? If you can, then you can conclude from everything I have given you in my answer (which is quite generous if I may say so). If you cannot answer that, then you *seriously need to review your notes, textbook, wikipedia etc*.

Comment: Ok, so I will review my notes again